# Anypoint-CLI. How can I see the CRL (Revocation List) digest in the load balancer?

Tags: mule, mule-studio, anypoint-studio

In mule anypoint-cli, how can I see the CRL digest?

I want to find out where this is so that I can compare it with other CRL digests so that I know exactly which one is in the load balancer?

Any help where to find this information using anypoint-cli or other would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The way to do this is that you use the json style response;

cloudhub load-balancer describe-json

And this will return you the revocationListDigest:

I was calling

cloudhub load-balancer describe

Which does not show you this information.